# Preview blade within another blade from different directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a laravel app structured to has separate resources for both customers and admins. Inside the app, on the admin side, I have checkboxes for controlling the visibility of some components on a front (customer) page. Now, in addition to the visibility, I have some extra params to display. So, in order to verify changes immediately,  I would like to preview (not include) `front.blade.php` inside `admin.blade.php`?

My only idea right now is to use `<iframe>`, but I am hoping to find something that is called "laravel way".

My project's structure :

```
resources
|-- admin
|    |-- views
|        |-- layouts
|            |-- website
|               `-- front.blade.php
|
|-- front
|    |-- views
|        |-- layouts
|            |-- website
|               `-- admin.blade.php
```

**admin.blade.php**

```
@section('section','Website')
@section('title','Home')
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('style')
    <link href="{{ admin_asset('assets/admin/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="contentbar">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Header</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        @include('website.front') <--- include doesn't work. It just brakes the whole view
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-footer">Footer</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('script')
    <script src="{{ admin_asset('assets/admin/js/main.min.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

**config/view.php**

```
'paths' => [
        resource_path('front/views'),
        resource_path('admin/views'),
    ],
```

Comment: Not really the "laravel way" but if you've built some sort of MVVM structure using e.g. React or Vue you can just poll the server or use [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting) to determine when a model has changed and load the changed model

Comment: @apokryfos even after doing so, I still need to display the whole view  `front.blade.php` inside the `admin.blade.php` as a component, don't I?

Comment: Not necessarity. If you structure your data correctly then you can update what is shown in the browser using JavaScript which is what view libraries can help you achieve

Comment: oh, sorry! I forgot to delete "don't I?" part. 

I really need to display `front` in `admin` :)

Comment: Your current code will display front in admin, however what I'm saying is whenever you need to update front, use JavaScript instead of a full page or iframe reload

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you change the default `resource\views` path and include all your organized view folder inside to be like :

```
    resources
|-- views
|    |-- admin
|        |-- layouts
|            |-- website
|               `-- front.blade.php
|
|    |-- front
|        |-- layouts
|            |-- website
|               `-- admin.blade.php
```

but if you want to keep your structure, so you have to make these changes to make it works:

**config/view.php**

```
'paths' => [
    resource_path('views'),
],
```

and in your blade you can do something like:

```
@include(resource_path('admin\views\layouts\website\front.blade.php'))
```